# constant expression required - vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create an URL that changes based on what I put in cell "A1", however, I keep getting a compile error "Constant expression required".

The error is on the second line at "banana".

```
 banana = Range("A1")

 Const URL As String = "http://openinsider.com/screener?s=" & banana & "&o=&pl=&ph=&ll=&lh=&fd=730&fdr=&td=0&tdr=&fdlyl=&fdlyh=&daysago=&xp=1&xs=1&vl=&vh=&ocl=&och=&sic1=-1&sicl=100&sich=9999&grp=0&nfl=&nfh=&nil=&nih=&nol=&noh=&v2l=&v2h=&oc2l=&oc2h=&sortcol=0&cnt=100&page=1"
 Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Integer = 4
```

Answer (score 3):

VBA expects a `Const URL`, but you are actually trying to use it as a dynamic variable `String`, not `Const`.

If you want your `URL` to be dynamic according to the value in `Range("A1")`, use the code below:

```
Dim banana As String
Dim URL As String

banana = Range("A1").Value
URL = "http://openinsider.com/screener?s=" & banana & "&o=&pl=&ph=&ll=&lh=&fd=730&fdr=&td=0&tdr=&fdlyl=&fdlyh=&daysago=&xp=1&xs=1&vl=&vh=&ocl=&och=&sic1=-1&sicl=100&sich=9999&grp=0&nfl=&nfh=&nil=&nih=&nol=&noh=&v2l=&v2h=&oc2l=&oc2h=&sortcol=0&cnt=100&page=1"
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually you are getting error because when you declare a constant, the value you give it must be constant too. You cannot declare a constant with a variable.

So declare like this,

Dim Banana as String 
Dim URL as String

Banana = sheets (1).Range ("A1"). Value

Use either If or Select Case here since URL will change as per value changes in A1,

URL = "https://as.com"

Then other code.

Comment: An `If` or `Select Case` is not required simply because a variable's value could change.  That is why programming languages have variables - so that they can be used in code and that code will use whatever the current value of the variable is.

Comment: Please check the original question,, person has written the URL will change if the value in A1 will and this can be executed only by testing THE A1, Logically.

Comment: No, you can write a statement such as `URL = "http://openinsider.com/screener?s=" & banana & "&o=&pl=&page=1"`, which will set `URL` to the string `"http://openinsider.com/screener?s="` concatenated with the current value of the variable `banana` concatenated with the string `"&o=&pl=&page=1"`.  You obviously can't include a variable when calculating the value of a constant but, providing `URL` is a variable and not a constant, you can calculate `URL` using a variable.  See [the answer by @ShaiRado](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43439970/6535336) for the correct way of doing this.